# Dynamic programming table for number of steps problem

Tags: dynamic-programming

There is a well known problem called "Triple Step" that states:

*"A child is running up a staircase with n steps and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps, or 3 steps at a time. Implement a method to count how many possible ways the child can run up the stairs"*

The algorithm below is a version without memoization:

```
int countWays(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return countWays(n-1) + countWays(n-2) + countWays(n-3);
    }
}
```

I know that its runtime can be improved from the exponential time complexity. 
But I really would like to know how to build a dynamic programming table over this problem,
for example I tried the table below for n being 4 steps:

```
   0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 <= staircase size
1  1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
2  1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3
3  1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 <=** There's something wrong because for n=4 the output should be 7
```

Could someone give me a hint about how this table could be built for the problem above? (or maybe the table is fine and I'm not able to interpret it right)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As you mentioned that countWays(N) can be solved by taking sum of countWays(N-1), countWays(N-2) and countWays(N-3).**

Since we know the answer for n<=0, we can start constructing our solution from n=0 to n=N and at any point of time we will always have N-1, N-2 and N-3 values ready to be used.

In the process of constructing solution from n=0 to n=N at any point of time we should have results of our earlier calculations stored somewhere.

you can take 3 variables to store these values and keep updating these 3 variables at each iteration to store the last 3 calculations.

```
int countWays(int n) {
    int last = 1; // for n = 0
    int secondLast = 0; // for n = -1
    int thridLast = 0; // for n = -2

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) {
        int current = last + secondLast + thirdLast;
        thirdLast = secondLast;
        secondLast = last;
        last = current;
    }
    return last;
}
```

instead of taking 3 variables you can store all the earlier calculations in an array and the code will look like this,

```
int countWays(int n) {
    if(n<0) return 0; 
    int[] a = new int[n+3];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 0;
    a[2] = 1; // stores the result for N=0

    for(int i = 3 ; i < n+3 ; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2] + a[i-3];
    }
    return a[n+2];
}
```

and array will look like,
Answer     -> [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7]
Value Of N ->  -2, -1,0 ,1, 2, 3, **4**

**Array created in this solutions is known is dynamic programming table also known as memoization or bottom up approach to DP**

Run time complexity of above solution is O(N)

There is another way to solve these type of problems in O(Log N) time complexity, where solution can be described in terms of a linear recurrence relation. 
The solution is known as Matrix Exponentiation, follow this link for more explanation - https://discuss.codechef.com/t/building-up-the-recurrence-matrix-to-compute-recurrences-in-o-logn-time/570

Answer (score 2):

The table for this is 1d which is the staircase size, on every step `x` you add `x-1`, `x-2`, and `x-3` if possible, for example:

```
         0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 <= staircase size
1st step 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0    only x-1 is possible
2nd step 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0    x-1 + x-2 are possible
3rd step 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 0    x-1 + x-2 + x-3 are possible
4th step 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 7    x-1 + x-2 + x-3 are possible
```

More explanation:

**Step 1:**

- only reachable by 1-step

**Step 2:**

- 1-step + 1-step
- 2-steps

**Step 3:**

- 1-step + 1-step + 1-step
- 1-step + 2-steps
- 2-steps + 1-step
- 3-steps

**Step 4:**

- 1-step + 1-step + 1-step + 1-step
- 2-steps + 1-step + 1-step
- 1-step + 2-steps + 1-step
- 1-step + 1-step + 2-steps
- 1-step + 3-steps
- 3-steps + 1-step
- 2-steps + 2-steps

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you are using dynamic programming to solve the problem.
Let `a` be the name of the variable of your table.

The formulae for `a[n]` with `n = 0, 1, 2, ....` are as you mentioned:

```
a[0] = 1
a[n] = a[n-1] + a[n-2] + a[n-3]
```

Be sure that `a[n]` for `n < 0` is `0` always.

The answer for `staircase size = 4` can be solved only if all the answers for `0 <= staircase size < 4` are given. i.e., `a[4]` can be calculated only if `a[0]`, `a[1]`, ..., `a[3]` are calculated.

The answer for `staircase size = 3` can be solved only if all the answers for `0 <= staircase size < 3` are given. i.e., `a[3]` can be calculated only if `a[0]`, ..., `a[2]` are calculated.

The answer for `staircase size = 2` can be solved only if all the answers for `0 <= staircase size < 2` are given. i.e., `a[2]` can be calculated only if `a[0]`, `a[1]` are calculated.

The answer for `staircase size = 1` can be solved only if all the answers for `0 <= staircase size < 1` are given. i.e., `a[1]` can be calculated only if `a[0]` is calculated.

`a[0]` is the first formula.

Here, you can start.

```
a[0] = 1  // Initialization
a[1] = a[0] + a[-1] + a[-2] = a[0] + 0 + 0  // calculated at 1st loop  (a[1] = 1)
a[2] = a[1] + a[0] + a[-1] = a[1] + a[0] + 0  // calculated at 2nd loop  (a[2] = 1 + 1)
a[3] = a[2] + a[1] + a[0]  // calculated at 3rd loop  (a[3] = 2 + 1 + 1)
a[4] = a[3] + a[2] + a[1]  // calculated at 4th loop  (a[4] = 4 + 2 + 1)
...
a[n] = a[n-1] + a[n-2] + a[n-3]  // calculated at nth loop
```